# Is there any operator or function to modify an attribute inside an element in an array in a mongoDB document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
let cartCheckItem = await Cart.findOne({ owner: req.body.onwer });
for (let i = 0; i < cartCheckItem.items.length; i++) {
  if (cartCheckItem.items[i].itemId == req.body.items[0].itemId) {
    let updateQty = await Cart.updateOne(
      { owner: req.body.owner },
      { $set: { qty: 2 } }
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to update the quantity of an item in a cart array in a mongoDB document

Answer (score 0):

You can `find` and `update` a doc in a single `aggregate` query like this:

```
await Cart.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "owner": req.body.onwer
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "qty": 2
    }
  }
]);
```

Or you can just use `updateOne` like this:

```
await Cart.updateOne(
{
  "owner": 5
},
{
  "$set": {
    qty: 2
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the first document that matches "owner" and the req.body.items[0].itemId which could be one of the elements in the "item" array, you can do

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({"owner":req.body.owner,"items":req.body.items[0].itemId},{$set:{ qty: 2 }})
```

Note: to find only a single element within an array field, u can directly do so as given in above query. [Refer here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)